# Someone who looks for problems and is not interested in solving an issue pragmatically

Tags: word-request, expressions

Is there a word or an expression for "Someone who looks for problems and is not interested in solving an issue pragmatically"?

In particular in my case I described a solution that was OK within the context given. Someone else presented a hypothetical situation: "If ... then it is not OK." Based on this hypothetical, they insisted that the solution I provided was not good. The hypothetical was an assumption, and it was completely unknown whether it would ever occur. My feeling is that this person merely wants to discredit my solution.

**What do you call such a person?**

I think this person wants to promote his/her own answer and is thus trying to find irrelevant "issues" with the answers of others.
But I would also be interested in the expression for someone who does it without bad motives.

Comment: Do they want to attack *you* personally? (If someone else proposed the same idea, would the person say the same thing?) Or are they fixated on that one "`...`" condition? (If you proposed a totally different idea, would the person say, "But I'm still worried about `...` and I think that solution doesn't solve it any better than your other idea"?) Or do they want to dismiss *any idea* proposed by *anyone* and will make up excuses to dislike any idea? Could you [edit] to give a little more information?

Comment: Good question. I think that person wants to promote his/her own answer and thus trying to find irrelevant *issues* in the answers of others.
But I would also be interested in the expression for someone who does it without bad motives too. I hope my explanation helps.

Comment: Do you want the word to capture the idea that the person is attempting to promote their own idea by attacking others'? Because that would be different from attacking *all* ideas (and not providing any, or at least not providing any that they aren't also attacking at the same time).

Comment: @KRyan I'm not sure if I understand the question. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I would like to answer this question, but as I lack rep in ELL, I'd like to proffer *obstructionist*. Definition: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obstructionist

Comment: Do you have to have rep in order to answer in this network? I'm surprised to read this. Thank you for the link though.

Comment: @Deepak You do not need any reputation to answer. (And you *do* need 50 reputation to leave a comment -- what you did here actually required *more* reputation! `:)` )

Comment: Is there a reason this is cross posted on both ELU and ELL? One of them needs to be removed as cross posting is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Catija I was hoping to find an answer in either. I thought it is good for both networks, also for those who want to learn. I see myself as being quite proficient in the English language; so I usually use the other network. But to be honest, there are English learners here who might benefit from that. I wonder why *cross posting* is strongly discouraged. Is it your opinion or do you base your remark on Q&A guidelines from the networks?

Comment: It is [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: I don't think in this case it is. 1. The English Learners will benefit from the question. You cannot expect them to be on the other network. 2. I am looking for input from sophisticated English speakers too. The link you provided is a meta discussion and it talks about StackOverflow and ServerFault; two networks of which you can say the topics are easier separable than in the two English networks. Feel free to start a discussion on meta; it might yield interesting opinions I think.

Comment: @Elyasin: I'm a little hurt that you don't think there are any sophisticated English speakers here ;) The problem chiefly is that synchronizing two questions on different sites is non-trivial, and you're not making any effort to do so anyway, so the result is that the *same* question gets a *whole different set* of often *partially redundant* answers. See also [Should we close questions that are exact duplicates of open ELU questions?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/636), where this discussion has been had, right here.

Comment: The INTP or ENTP personality from Myers Briggs may give some insight into this person and their personality.  Just a guess, but I suspect they enjoy the debate.  Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might say that the person is *being [**contrary**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/contrary2)*:

> (usually of children) behaving badly; choosing to do or say the opposite of what is expected

*Contrary* usually means "in opposition to" or "opposite of":

> The president's new tax plan is hard on poor families, which is contrary to what he promised when he was elected.

But when *contrary* applies to a person, it means the person disagrees with any suggestion.

The noun ***contrarian*** means "someone who behaves in a contrary way, especially with respect to popular opinion".

Comment: ...and the noun form is _"contrarian."_

Answer (score 12):

Such a person could be described as a ***naysayer***, one who consistently criticizes and objects to anything proposed.

Comment: I like the sound if this word, never knew it exists! So basically a naysayer is someone who tries to deny all possible solutions for the sake of their own. Interesting.

Comment: @Scarl: Strictly speaking, a naysayer is one who rejects or criticizes or badmouths whatever proposals are made — not necessarily with an eye toward putting their own forward, although that's possible, but especially with no real visible agenda or apparent reason for doing so other than pessimism.

Answer (score 3):

A person who tries to poke holes in the logic/reasoning/solutions of others is sometimes playing the role of Devil's Advocate. (One who argues against a cause or position, not as a committed opponent but simply for the sake of argument or to determine the validity of the cause or position.)  This might be annoying but is not usually done with overt bad intention.

I can't think of a good term for someone who is doing this type of thing with bad intention.

Comment: My first thought was ***naysayer*** is a positively *Victorian* usage. But apparently [it's experiencing a real resurgence in recent decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=naysayer%2Cnitpicker&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnaysayer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnitpicker%3B%2Cc0). I'm to old to change [back] though, so I'll be sticking with ***nitpicker***.

Answer (score 3):

This type of behavior is considered ***bad faith***.
Thus the person you described, would be ***acting in bad faith***

Always remember, this is very much an accusation. As in your example, it would indicate they were never actually interested in a solution.

Comment: This isn't exactly wrong, but it's rather over-general; it's perfectly possible to act in bad faith in all sorts of ways that have nothing to do with finding (real or imagined) faults in a proposed solution.

Comment: I agree it's general, but I don't think it's overly general, the example is just a very specific situation.  This also would only be applicible to the example with intent.   Without intent, then naysayer or in conversational "hater" would be a much better fit.

Comment: Bad faith also only describes the behavoir, not the individual, who would be clearly duplicitous.  it's general but i dont think closer words exist for a bad faith critque.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for **carper** or **caviler**. Both mean *one who raises irritating and trivial objections, or finds faults unnecessarily*

Comment: Both are somewhat uncommon words, but I think capture the meaning quite well. I wasn't familiar with caviler, so thanks for the new word! While looking it up, I also came across pettifogger, which is another great word I wasn't familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

If such a person acted in bad faith I'd describe them as an **unfair or dishonest** person but if their position were neutral they might be called **critic, skeptic or negativist** or if you like an expression: **doubtful Thomas**.

Answer (score 1):

Such a person may be thought a sophist.  Originally I think sophists were considered clever and could argue either side of an issue (from Ancient Greek teachings), but the name today connotes one of specious reasoning.

Comment: Sophist is an interesting addition, but to me it has more to do with how convoluted their reasoning or argument is than picking apart someone else's solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If the person is simply resisting change for no reason then "stick in the mud" would fit.

Comment: That really doesn't capture the sense that the asker is looking for. To me a "stick in the mud" is more of a miserable person that refuses to have any fun or change their circumstances to something better. There's no connection with nit picking someone else's ideas to death.

Answer (score 1):

Bear with me for a while when suggesting **detail-oriented** to describe this person.

When reading your context I recognised/remembered some similar situations I've been in myself, where I tend to present very detailed issues or problems with a presented solution. Usually this is not to be mean, but merely a representation of how I perceive and respond to solution due to my personality type.

This is based on theory from the [Myers-Briggs Type Indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Briggs_Type_Indicator), and regarding this specific topic see [Are You a Big Picture Thinker or Detail-Oriented?](http://quickbase.intuit.com/blog/2011/03/17/are-you-a-big-picture-thinker-or-detail-oriented/). And the very brief summary of this is that this particular person is *detail-oriented* and as such the natural response is to respond to details.

Due note that often this response indirectly is an approval of the idea, but to them there exists some minor issues they would like to address. If you are a big picture thinker, these suggestions is often conceived as critic or condemnation of the idea, which often is *not* the case.

Comment: This is not a psychology or workplace relations forum, this is an English language usage forum.  This comment is inappropriate.  Also: it's __Myers__ with an "s", __Myers-Briggs__ is hyphenated when referring to the MBTI, the theory underpinning the MBTI is called Type by its adherents, and, finally, in your use of "detail-oriented" in this "answer" and your use of Type in a comment above, you seem to be badly confusing the N/S and J/P axes.

Comment: @Codeswitcher, Corrected spelling. I know this is a language forum, but felt that the context given opted for an answer which required a slightly different approach. Have avoided going deeply into the MBTI side as it is language forum, but I do believe my main point will stand that _detail-oriented_ could be the word the OP is looking for